# How to avoid the issue of appending request parameters when using display tag with struts and tiles

Tags: struts2

I was using display tag in the jsp with struts and tiles. It works fine, but it always appends the parameters int the url for each request. If the url size is more than 250 the url is breaking. How to avoid the problem of appending the request parameters for every request using the display tag with struts and tiles

Answer (score 1):

use excludeParams="*" in  tag, it will chop off the unnecessary request parameters.